# Logic regarding some code to find everything not in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, what I've written below does this (to my knowledge and how it's outputting):

1) I've found where Zip, City, State, and Bank Name match. ~ 3786 records

2) I've combined that with where just City, State, Name matches (minus Zip). ~4390 records

Combined I have 8176 records.

What I'm trying to find next is the rest of the table (18,288 records total, so roughly 10,000 left over) that didn't get picked up in those 2 queries equaling 8,176.

Any idea on how to find that?

My `BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_ZIP_5_010` table is just splitting out a table, acting as the source table for all 18,288 records.

My `BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_SWIFT_US_LPAD_SMALLZIP_SPLIT_CITY_STATE` table is acting as another source table, where I formatted Columns correctly.

My `BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030` combines those two tables above on Zip, State, City, Name and filteres where BIC is not null. Bic is just a bank code.

```
SELECT SWIFT_US.BIC, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.RoutingNumber, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankName, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankCity, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankStateCd, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankZip_5, 
       'Second Pass' AS Phase 
FROM dbo.BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_ZIP_5_010 AS FED_ACH_5ZIP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_SWIFT_US_LPAD_SMALLZIP_SPLIT_CITY_STATE AS SWIFT_US 
        ON FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankName = SWIFT_US.INSTITUTION_NAME 
        AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankCity = SWIFT_US.CITYNEW 
        AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankStateCd = SWIFT_US.STATENEW
/*AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankZip_5 = SWIFT_US.ZIPNEW    */ 
WHERE (SWIFT_US.BIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.RoutingNumber NOT IN
                        (SELECT RoutingNumber
                         FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030)

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'First Pass' AS Phase
FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a more efficient and elegant way, but can't you implement `NOT` in each query to get the rest of the population?

Comment: @Hatt -- do you mean, taking out the NOT to find where the fields are NULL? I'm currently finding where they are not NULL.

Comment: No the logical `NOT` - so something like `WHERE (SWIFT_US.BIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND NOT(FED_ACH_5ZIP.RoutingNumber NOT IN
                        (SELECT RoutingNumber
                         FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030))`

Comment: That gives me 5,908 out of the 10,112 that are not being picked up by Phase 1 and 2 when ran on it's own.

However, something interesting is when I UNION ALL that with the Phase 1 and Phase 2, I get a record count of 17,870. Why is that?

Comment: So there's nothing in common between the 3786 and the 4390? One thing I can definitely say is that using a left join and then afterward looking for not null on the right side is not going to do what you expect.

Comment: @shawn00 I apologize, what should it do since I'm not grasping it? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Are you sure there's no overlap between 1) and 2)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a simple EXCEPT clause -

```
SELECT *
FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_ZIP_5_010

EXCEPT

(
SELECT SWIFT_US.BIC, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.RoutingNumber, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankName, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankCity, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankStateCd, 
       FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankZip_5, 
FROM dbo.BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_ZIP_5_010 AS FED_ACH_5ZIP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_SWIFT_US_LPAD_SMALLZIP_SPLIT_CITY_STATE AS SWIFT_US 
        ON FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankName = SWIFT_US.INSTITUTION_NAME 
        AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankCity = SWIFT_US.CITYNEW 
        AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankStateCd = SWIFT_US.STATENEW
/*AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankZip_5 = SWIFT_US.ZIPNEW    */ 
WHERE (SWIFT_US.BIC IS NOT NULL) 
AND FED_ACH_5ZIP.RoutingNumber NOT IN
                        (SELECT RoutingNumber
                         FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_NDIST_BIC_ZIP_5_030
)
```

Comment: This helped a little! I'm getting a record count of 18,675. I had to add the same Select Clause through the Left Outer Join in order for the Union ALL to work... I'm assuming that inflated my record count?

I realized what I wrote before was too hard to look at, so I decided to explain it to my best ability instead. :) @Ankit

Comment: @Lizzie, I didn't get it. Do you need to add this into the above query?

Comment: This helped a little! I'm getting a record count of 18,675. I had to add the same Select Clause through the Left Outer Join in order for the Union ALL to work... I'm assuming that inflated my record count?

Comment: If your inner query is giving you the record count of 8,176 and table `BM_BNKA_FLATFILE_FEDACHDIR2018_ZIP_5_010` hae 18000 records then definitely you will get 10000 left records with above query. Where is the gap now?

Comment: That's why I am confused too, because it should do that! Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YyqA8jX.png) of what I have written. Again, I added in what I did because my fields were not matching up for the UNION ALL.

Comment: Ok. If you just run the inner query, What count you get?

Comment: I added in the 

`FED_ACH_5ZIP.BankZip_5 = SWIFT_US.ZIPNEW` 

to my First Query and that helped bring my row count down to 18,369.

Comment: If I run the first inner query (Second pass) I get 4,390. The second inner query (First Pass) I get 3786.

When I run the main query, before the EXCEPT I get a row count of 22,548. I believe that is my issue. lol

Comment: For the 'All Records' query, I need to LOJ on the SWIFT_US table because it has BIC, which my FED_ACH_5ZIP does not have.

Comment: `except` isn't going to do anything when you have that phase column in there.

Comment: @shawnt00, Completely agree and updated the answer.